# Apitome sidebar disappears when included in a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-api-documentation, apitome

I am using the `rspec_api_documentation` and `apitome` gems in a version 5.2 ruby on rails app.

This produces excellent documentation, and has a sidebar (div#sidebar) to allow quick access to the correct part of the documentation. When I choose the

```
config.layout = "layouts/application.html.erb"
```

option in the `apitome.rb` initializer, the documentation is rendered, but the sidebar has disappeared. Looking at the page source, the code for the sidebar is not being rendered, i.e. it is not a css problem, the html is not being put into the layout.  To make sure it was not something unusual in my application.html.erb file, I simplified it to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
        <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

This sidebar is very useful, so how do I render it in a layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response to [this issue](https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome/issues/98), I was able to solve this.

I created a new layout at `app/views/layouts.apidocs.html.erb` which  rendered `apitome/docs/navigation`.  A simple example would be as follows

```
# app/views/layouts/apidocs.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary">
            <%= render 'apitome/docs/navigation' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8" role="main">
          <div class="docs-section">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I then configured this layout in the 
apitome initialiser.

```
# config/initializers/apitome
Apitome.setup do |config|
   ...
   config.layout = "layouts/apidocs.html.erb"
end
```

After some  css tinkering, it all looked good.